# Criteria-Based Sharing

Tags: sharing, criteria-based-sharing

There seems to be a discrepancy in the documentation for Criteria-Based Sharing Rules.

The Guide to Sharing Architecture (and other sources) states that:

"Only Manual Share Records can be created on standard objects".

Yet, the help section:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_sharing_cbs_about.htm&language=en_US

states:  "You can create criteria-based sharing rules for accounts, opportunities, cases, contacts, leads, campaigns, and custom objects."

I'm studying for certification and need clarification.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> "Only Manual Share Records can be created on standard objects".

The above sentence is definitely incorrect. It must be a documentation error or a (failed) attempt to describe some other limitation or Manual Sharing.

> "You can create criteria-based sharing rules for accounts,
>   opportunities, cases, contacts, leads, campaigns, and custom objects."

The above is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing rules or criteria based sharing rules comes under "Force.com Managed sharing".

Manual sharing can be done two ways.
- User Managed sharing (via apex code) with standard sharing reason "Manual" (This can be for both custom/standard object)
-  Apex managed sharing(via apex code with custom sharing reasons) (This is available only for custom object)

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_Apex_Managed_Sharing_to_Create_Custom_Record_Sharing_Logic